# The left arm of my mesh won't bend properly despite being set up exactly like the right arm

Tags: modeling, mesh, rigging, bones

I've been working on this stylized model and the left arm of my mesh won't bend properly despite being set up exactly like the right arm.

If need be, let me know how to attach the .blend file.

Left shoulder is detaching but the right shoulder is fine

[image: left shoulder is detaching but the right shoulder is fine]

[image]

Comment: Hello, you can upload your file on https://blend-exchange.com/ read the instructions and share the link

Comment: done! any help you can offer is appreciated.

Comment: thanks but the character you share has no left arm

Comment: life continues to get worse

Comment: could you please give him his left arm?

Comment: sorry for getting back to you late, i have added his arm back and attempted to rig it just like how i had it, let me know if you need anything else

Answer (score 2):

It's close to [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/296611/why-is-individual-bone-weight-assignment-working-this-poorly/296616?noredirect=1#comment511469_296616). Maybe first align the character and armature to the front view, apply the scale and rotation of both the 2 objects, duplicate the right arm, deparent (*Clear and Keep Transformation*), mirror it with <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>-1</kbd>, as it will flip the normals, select all in *Edit* mode and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>, parent With *Automatic Weights*, correct a bit in *Weight Paint* mode.