# Why is individual bone weight assignment working this poorly?

Tags: rigging, armature, weight-painting, weight-paint-mode

[image]
image of the option i selected, my armature and my mesh. You can see just the light blue on the upper arm.

File is available at https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FZGquO3hvS9c2O7s_zqeI7c5YH8lC-vi/view .

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FZGquO3hvS9c2O7s_zqeI7c5YH8lC-vi/view?usp=sharing]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you keep the pieces separate, but to fix your problem you need to apply the scale (which is negative on Y for the moment), then in *Edit* mode recalculate the normals with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>. Now *Assign Automatic from Bones* again.

Comment: my thought is that i want the weights of the limbs which pass through the torso/head piece to be easily weight painted separately.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean but does my answer fix your problem?

Comment: It hasn't unfortunately :/ .

Comment: Have you 1) applied the scale 2) recalculated the normals?

Comment: yes, i have. Now weights not even improper ones come onto the weight-paint data..? I think maybe it's trying to apply automatic weights to where there was already data but it's pink when you click on that bone's influence.

Comment: It works for me, not sure why it doesn't for you, i hope someone will understand...  :/

Comment: thank you for trying ;)

Comment: Moonboots's answer works for me on the file you provided.  I wrote a more detailed answer, but then deleted it because there's little point.  The *order* in which you apply scale, recalculate normals matters.  The gravy is that applying the scale flips the normals because one negative scale axis, and then your bone is outside the mesh, so autoweights ignores it.